# Anaconda "conda info --all" has not showed my proxy settings

Tags: anaconda

I typed

```
proxy_servers:
  http: http://127.0.0.1:8855
```

on my ".condarc"(my HTTP proxy does not have a password or username )

This configuration file is located in the root directory. That is, the file that automatically opens in anaconda when I type ".condarc"

I use "conda info --all" want to check my proxy work or not
but there is no any proxy settings info

so how I know my proxy work or not?

```
    active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Z\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\torto\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Z\Anaconda3\.condarc
          conda version : 4.12.0
    conda-build version : 3.15.1
         python version : 3.7.0.final.0
       virtual packages : __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : C:\Z\Anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : C:\Z\Anaconda3\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Z\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\torto\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\torto\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Z\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\torto\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\torto\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.12.0 requests/2.19.1 CPython/3.7.0 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19041
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False

# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Z\Anaconda3

sys.version: 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 08:04:48) [...
sys.prefix: C:\Z\Anaconda3
sys.executable: C:\Z\Anaconda3\python.exe
conda location: C:\Z\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda
conda-build: C:\Z\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-build.exe
conda-convert: C:\Z\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-convert.exe
conda-develop: C:\Z\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-develop.exe
conda-env: C:\Z\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-env.exe
conda-index: C:\Z\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-index.exe
conda-inspect: C:\Z\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-inspect.exe
conda-metapackage: C:\Z\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-metapackage.exe
conda-render: C:\Z\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-render.exe
conda-server: C:\Z\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-server.exe
conda-skeleton: C:\Z\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-skeleton.exe
user site dirs:

CIO_TEST: <not set>
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV: base
CONDA_EXE: C:\Z\Anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe
CONDA_EXES: "C:\Z\Anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe"
CONDA_PREFIX: C:\Z\Anaconda3
CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER: (base)
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE: C:\Z\Anaconda3\python.exe
CONDA_ROOT: C:\Z\Anaconda3
CONDA_SHLVL: 1
CURL_CA_BUNDLE: <not set>
HOMEPATH: \Users\torto
PATH: C:\Z\Anaconda3;C:\Z\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Z\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Z\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Z\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Z\Anaconda3\bin;C:\Z\Anaconda3;C:\Z\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Z\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Z\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Z\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Z\Anaconda3\bin;C:\Z\Anaconda3\condabin;C:\z\Python38\Scripts;C:\z\Python38;C:\Z\Python39\Scripts;C:\Z\Python39;C:\Z\python310\Scripts;C:\Z\python310;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Users\torto\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.;C:\Z\Microsoft VS Code\bin
PSMODULEPATH: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: <not set>
SSL_CERT_FILE: <not set>
```

Answer (score 2):

All Conda configuration settings applied to current shell can be shown with `conda config --show`. To view only a specific key and its value, one can use, for example,

```bash
conda config --show proxy_servers
```

Comment: OH,you save me... but whatever,I still not knowing the proxy work or not.
thank you. :)